# Android Studio doesn't see BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, flutter-freezed

[image]

**Android Studio doesn't see BlocProvider**

When I try to add BlocProvider to HomePage, Android Studio doesn't see it and of cource i can't use it.
in the project i use `freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0`

> **main.dart**

```
    import 'package:rick_and_morty/ui/pages/home_page.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({super.key});

    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Rick and Morty',
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          fontFamily: 'Georgia',
          textTheme: const TextTheme(
            headline1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
            headline2: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.white),
            headline3: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
            bodyText2: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
            bodyText1: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200, color: Colors.white),
            caption: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 11.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
        home: HomePage(title: 'Rick and Morty'),
        );
      }
     }
```

> **home_page.dart**

```
    import 'package:rick_and_morty/data/repositories/character_repo.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    HomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

    final String title;
    final repository = CharacterRepo();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
          ),
        ),
        body: BlocProvider(

        ),
       );
      }
    }
```

> **pubspec.yaml**

```
    description: A new Flutter project.

    publish_to: 'none' 

    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
      json_annotation: ^4.7.0
      json_serializable: ^6.4.0
      bloc: ^8.0.0
      http: ^0.13.5

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter

      flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
      freezed: ^2.1.1
      build_runner: ^2.2.1

    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 1):

`BlocProvider` provided by [`flutter_bloc`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc), include `flutter_bloc` on your `pubspec.yaml`

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1 // use version based on package
```

More about [bloclibrary](https://bloclibrary.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  json_serializable: ^6.4.0
  http: ^0.13.5
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  freezed: ^2.1.1
  build_runner: ^2.2.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```